# How to get quiz options button color red or green if a selected option is wrong?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am creating a quiz app in which when i clicked one option if it is correct it appears green and if it is incorrect it appears red but highlights the correct option green of that question also so thats why user know on the spot which is correct answer
plz give me answer i am new in coding.

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't it work?